# Replicating Mac "drag and drop" behaviour in Windows

Tags: windows, mac

On a Mac computer, when dragging a file or folder from a Finder window to an application's modal file selection window, the modal window navigates to the location of the dragged file or folder, and that file or folder is selected.

On a Windows computer, when dragging a file or folder from an Explorer window to an application's modal file selection window, the behaviour can be configured to copy, move or shortcut creation, but no similar functionality to the Mac behaviour exists. Is there any software to allow for this behaviour on Windows?

Thanks.

Comment: I wish it did, but after years of looking, I've never found anything.  Also, there is a SW for the Mac called Default Folder that has even easier feature like this.  In an open/save dialog, you can move your cursor over an open Finder window in the background and click it to make the dialog change to that folder.  So, I like this question and welcome any suggestions, but I'm sure someone will close this question with the standard "SW recommendations are not allowed"...

Comment: I do know of this, which was linked in another thread on here on the same topic - https://www.listary.com/quick-switch. And I certainly agree, this is very intuitive functionality and I'm surprised that there aren't other threads here and elsewhere asking for solutions to this.